# Viewing rendered HTML in IntelliJ IDEA 10

Tags: html, intellij-idea

Is there any way to view an HTML file in IntelliJ fully rendered?  I have a simple HTML file with a listing of links in a project.  When I view the file I see this:

```
<a href="http://address1">link 1</a>
<a href="http://address2">link 2</a>
<a href="http://address3">link 3</a>
```

I would like to open the file in IntelliJ and have it show the rendered HTML instead:

```
link 1
link 2
link 3
```

This way I can avoid launching it in an external browser.

Comment: May be a good idea to ask this over in http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/idea/ideacommunity?view=discussions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: No.

But, honestly, because one of the issues we all know about all-so-well is the (now) minor differences in browsers - it's best to test in all of the real browsers anyways.

This is why they give you this convenient little menu in the upper right of the document:

[image]

Comment: +1 I was in a middle of taking the exact same screenshot! It hard to get this to show up though.

Comment: Thanks Steve.  I knew about the little floating menu bar.  I was hoping there was an option for simple HTML.  Thank-you for the prompt reply.

Answer (score 0):

**For HTML view in IDEA**

move your mouse cursor  to the upper right corner of the page, or type  ALT+F2, you will see a small pop-up menu with the icons for various browsers. Click one to launch it in that browser. 
Configure the locations of the browser executables in File > Settings > IDE Settings > Web Browsers